# How to do ocr fast in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab

The task is relative simple. It only needs to recognize numbers. The speed needs to be fast (within 0.5 seconds in a 2016 computer). A sample picture is attached. I need to create a function which contain recognize those two sets of numbers in the attached picture and put those into two arrays. I tried to use the OCR function in MATLAB computer vision toolbox. It produced many errors and the speed is very slow.

I am thinking to predefine 10 digits (0 to 9) and then use pixel to pixel comparison. I think that it will give high accuracy, but the speed will be slow.

Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Did you specify the character set in `ocr`? That might speed things up a bit. If you're using nice clean images like this, then segmentation and template matching might be an option as well.

Comment: I played with the OCR Trainer, but it does not work well because of the digits are so close and the color are difference of digit

Comment: This is precisely why you see so many questions with comments asking for code and "what have you tried".

Comment: About the color: Since the image is so clean i'd turn it into a binary image.